# netbeans, xml autocomplete for attributes fails for default namespace

Tags: netbeans, xml-editor

I've defined two namespaces: beans, aop.

If you cut & paste into a Netbeans the tag that i've written below, and you try to edit a tag inside beans:beans you should observe this behavior:

> <beans:import />

typing this the autocomplete assists you, and after the element name, it proposes the list of attributes (in this case just one).

> <aspectj-autoproxy />

typing this the autocomplete dosn't propose the list of attributes (there are two attributes: proxy-target-class, expose-proxy)

It happens for the attributes of the  default namespace's elements.

Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

I've tested on NB 6.9 and NB 7.0

thanks in advance

```
<beans:beans
       xmlns:beans ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

  try here

</beans:beans>
```